# Get count of a datatable column contains with specific value

Tags: asp.net, linq

How to get the total of specific column contains with specific string drom datatable.

I followed as like below but not getting :

```
int count = _dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<string> 
("EffectiveShow").Equals("0")).count;
```

There "EffectiveShow" is my column name.  In that column I need the count of string "0".

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252934/getting-a-count-of-rows-in-a-datatable-that-meet-certain-criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
int count = _dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c["EffectiveShow"].ToString()=="0").ToList().Count;
```

Comment: Error 104 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Getting this error.

Comment: I think you don't need to convert it to list, just call `.Count()` on .Where results.

Comment: No, it's not getting even directly appending to where. It's generating error like inaccessible of count.

Comment: You could try this                                                                                    var results = from r in _dt
              where r.EffectiveShow == "0"
              select r;
var count = results.Count();